# How to pass options via Rake to Yard to Kramdown to use GFM

Tags: ruby, rake, yard, kramdown

I've a gem that I've produced with some docs written with [Github Flavoured markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#syntax-highlighting) (GFM) to take advantage of their syntax highlighting.

Unfortunately, Github decided to use their own syntax for code block fencing (three backticks) so to get [Yardoc](http://yardoc.org) to parse that correctly I've chosen Kramdown as the parser, which [supports GFM](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/parser/gfm.html).

On top of that, when I push the code up to Rubygems the documentation will be generated by running the Rake task (as far as I understand). So I need to find a way to tell Yard to use the Kramdown GFM parser, via Rake.

Kramdown selects the parser via the `-i` switch:

```
$ bin/kramdown --help

Command line options:

    -i, --input ARG
          Specify the input format: kramdown (default), html, GFM or markdown
```

But I don't know how to get Yard to pass that, either via the `yard` binary or through Rake. I suppose this could be possible by creating a Yardoc plugin, but I've never done that and not sure if it would work, and it also seems like things would be getting out of hand at that point!

What I'd *really* like is a markdown standard for this, but that's not so much a question as an unfulfilled desire… I'm not sure Stack Overflow can help with those so much.

Comment: We had a [similar issue with the Haml docs](https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/744). At the time I couldn’t find any friendly way to get Yard to pass options through to the markdown provider (it might have changed since). Note that Github also supports triple tilde (`~~~`) as well as triple backticks for fenced code blocks so you could switch and use that syntax instead.

Comment: According to the [changelog](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) , GFM should be working out of the box since yardoc version 0.7.4. Maybe you can find more info / ideas for your case [here](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/404).

Comment: @matt Ah, I didn't realise they accepted that too, that would be a good tradeoff. Thanks.

Comment: @egwspiti That's very informative. I checked Rubygems and it had rendered correctly, just couldn't get it to work locally. Installing Redcarpet fixed it locally. I've not been able to get Kramdown to work but I'm not going to sweat it now I have 2 alternatives, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran across this issue and was having trouble finding clear guidance anywhere, so after digging around in Yard’s issues and source I came up with this approach and am pretty happy with it. Hopefully it might be helpful to someone else who comes across this thread.

1. Add a Ruby file for Yard customizations. If you have additional docs in a `docs/` folder, then `docs/yard_support.rb` might be a good place. In it, add a custom markup provider for Yard.

   ```rb
   # docs/yard_support.rb
   require 'kramdown'
   require 'kramdown-parser-gfm'

   # Custom markup provider class that always renders Kramdown using GFM (Github
   # Flavored Markdown). You could add additional customizations here, or even
   # call a different Markdown library altogether, like `commonmarker`.
   # The only requirement is that your class supports:
   #   - `#initialize(markdown_text, options_hash)`
   #   - `#to_html()`, which just returns the converted HTML source
   class KramdownGfmDocument < Kramdown::Document
       def initialize(source, options = {})
           options[:input] = 'GFM' unless options.key?(:input)
           super(source, options)
       end
   end

   # Register the new provider as the highest priority option for Markdown.
   # Unfortunately there's no nice interface for registering your provider; you
   # just have to insert it directly at the front of the array. :\
   # See also:
   # - https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1157
   # - https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/1017
   # - https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/main/lib/yard/templates/helpers/markup_helper.rb
   YARD::Templates::Helpers::MarkupHelper::MARKUP_PROVIDERS[:markdown].insert(
       0,
       { const: 'KramdownGfmDocument' }
   )
   ```
2. Use `--load <path_to_the_above_file>` in your `.yardopts` file:

   ```
   # .yardopts
   --load docs/yard_support.rb
   ```